# using WebClient and receiving Error 403

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm currently using `WebClient` to open a few websites but after a period of time I start receiving `Error 403` messages.
I'm assuming it's because I'm hitting their servers to frequently/quickly.  I'm assuming all I need to do is add a `Thread.Sleep` time-frame between requests.

Since I'm having to do this a large number of times is there a suggestion on how to handle the throttling issue without have to take a tremendous amount of time?
For instance 3 secs between requests will end up taking me like 3 hrs to do.

So the question is, is `Thread.Sleep` really the right solution for this?  and if it is, what is a good time-frame for it?

As a side note I have also used `HttpWebRequest` and ran into the same problem.  I do still use it in other code projects and technically am hoping to utilize the same solution (or close to it) for these other code projects utilizing the `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: are you running your requests in sequence?

Comment: @esskar  currently yes I am.

Comment: Have you considered interleaving your requests, by that I mean: given k websites you have to open every T seconds, you always open them in the same sequence, depending on how long each 'open' operation takes this may give you some time between requests.
Whether it will be enough to avoid the error you reported is a completely different matter though.

Comment: Are you having to authenticate with any of these websites 1st?

Comment: @AndreaScarcella so what you mean is do website 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 1, then 2, etc. for however many number of items per website?

Comment: @JLWarlow No, I don't have to authenticate with any of the sites.

Comment: @shadonar: in principle I do, but I do not know what you are planning to do so my suggestion might need to be adapted.
In that regard what exactly do you mean by opening?
scraping the page, accessing an api?

Comment: @AndreaScarcella the focus for this question will be just accessing an api.  I have another project that will be scraping pages, and I'm hoping this solution might help with that project as well.

Comment: @shadonar: thank you for your feedback, then I believe you could procedd as I suggested, call api on website 1, then on website 2 and so forth.

Comment: Obviously this solution is inherently less efficient than a parallel one, on the other hand you are already running request sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

try running the requests in parallel

```
public static void RunRequest(Uri uri, Action<string> onCompleted)  
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => onCompleted(e.Result);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
};
```

warning: code is not testet and i have never used `WebClient`

```
private const int _maxParallelRequest = 10;
private int _requestCount = 0;
private readonly object _sync = new object();
private ManualResetEvent _ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);

while(true)
{
    foreach (var uri in _allYourUris)
    {
        var wait = false;
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_requestCount >= _maxParallelRequest)
                wait = true;
        }

        if (!wait)
        {
            lock (_sync) { ++_requestCount; }
            RunRequest(uri, r => {
                lock (_sync) 
                { 
                    --_requestCount; 
                    _ev.Set();
                }    
                // handle r
            });
            continue;
        }
        _ev.WaitOne();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```